# Check connection for url - image load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make some script where i load many images from other sites. When it finish load i do:

```
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){

     alert('OK');
     ....   /// do masonry layout
});
```

But i have problem when some img url is not available - script whole time try to load images from url with which he cant connect and function from imagesLoaded isnt executed. How can i resolve this problem and remove img that doesnt want to load from loading, after for example 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
 <span onclick="checkurlExist()">Click me!</span>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkurlExist()    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://yoururl.com/image.png",
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert("URL not found");
                }
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ok but i get error after 30 seconds - so it doesnt change anything, without this i also must wait 30 second to get no photo.